# Postgresql check constraint gives error, but the value (text) is correct

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

I have table `test` created using Dbeaver with columns:

`str::text`

and check constraint is: `(('str'::text = 'koko'::text))`

that's the only column and DDL for table is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.test (
    str text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_check CHECK (('str'::text = 'koko'::text))
);
```

I am inserting into table:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.test(str) VALUES ('koko');
```

which gives error:

```
SQL Error [23514]: ERROR: new row for relation "test" violates check constraint "test_check"
  Detail: Failing row contains (koko).
```

Why is that an error if the text is correct?

Comment: `CONSTRAINT test_check CHECK (str = 'koko')`

Comment: Being in single quotes, 'str' is just literal text, not a column name.  Obviously the string 'str' is not the same string of text as 'koko' is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice the comment before thinking about this, so I'll just scoop the answer. If you look at the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS), it is clear how the constraint should be written.

CONSTRAINT test_check CHECK (str = 'koko'::text)